# If $g$ is continuous and $f$ is s.t $f=g$ for $|x|<1$ then $f$ is continuous at 0

Tags: analysis, continuity

> If $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $|x|<1$ then $f$ is continuous at 0.

Attempt;
My claim is this statement is true;
On the open interval $(-1,1)$ $f(x)=g(x)$ and $g(x)$ is continuous everywhere.
So if $g$ is continuous at 0, then as at 0 $f=g$ $ must also be continuous at 0.

Is this correct??

Comment: Yes, continuity is a "local" property. However, I recommend that you actually write down a proof of it to make sure.

Comment: How would I got about writing the proof?

Comment: Would I state the definition of continuity of f at 0 and g at 0 and say they are equivalent as $f=g$?

Comment: Yes, in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, you need to choose $\delta < 1$. That is all.

Comment: Thank You very much for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $g$ is continuous at $0$, there exists $1 > \delta > 0$ such that $|g(x) - g(0)| < \varepsilon$ for all $|x| < \delta$. Since $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $|x| < \delta < 1$, it follows that $|f(x) - f(0)| < \varepsilon$ for all $|x| < \delta$. Thus, $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: $\delta<1$ is a non-sequitur, but at least it is a wlog.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the choice of $\delta$.